# Xamarin render Page in Page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a requirement to be able to display a ContentPage within a ContentPage.  All the current Xamarin content controls only allow a View as their content.  Having a content control that has a Page as content opens up quite a few possibilities so I am keen to get this working.

I have created a custom control that has a ContentPage as content and can renderer the child page successful on Android.  However the rendered child page does not have its children rendered.  See the renderer below but I am just getting the correct renderer for the child page and setting it.  What do I have to do get the child's page children rendering.  I would have thought its renderer would have taken care of this?

The host control

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp.Views.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    public class PageViewContainer: View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Content",
                                                                                          typeof(ContentPage),
                                                                                          typeof(PageViewContainer));

        public ContentPage Content
        {
            get { return (ContentPage)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

The Android renderer that successfully renders the child page but for some reason the child's page content is not rendered.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using TestApp.Views.Controls;
using Android.Content;
using System.ComponentModel;
using TestApp.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PageViewContainer), typeof(PageViewContainerRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.Renderers
{
    public class PageViewContainerRenderer : ViewRenderer<PageViewContainer, Android.Views.View>
    {
        public PageViewContainerRenderer(Context context): base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PageViewContainer> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var pageViewContainer = e.NewElement as PageViewContainer;
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ChangePage(e.NewElement.Content);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Content")
            {
                ChangePage(Element.Content);
            }
        }

        private void ChangePage(ContentPage page)
        {
            if (page != null)
            {
                var renderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(page, this.Context);
                SetNativeControl(renderer.View);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Pages.PageInPage"
             xmlns:custom_controls="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views.Controls">
    <ContentPage.Content>    
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <custom_controls:PageViewContainer
                Grid.Row="0"
                Content="{Binding ChildPage}">
            </custom_controls:PageViewContainer>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="1"
                Text="A Label"
                FontSize="Large">
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Child page that has the page renderer (as the red background appears) but the child label is not rendered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Easilog.Forms.Views.Pages.Account.ChildPage
             BackgroundColor="Red">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <Label
                Text="A child label that is not rendering :-("
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="Large">
            </Label>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: If you want to render the label, I think you should try to use`var renderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(page.Content, this.Context);` in your `ChangePage()` method